# Can we use Catalina Controls in GUI Extensions?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I understand SDL Web uses a mix of "Anguilla" and "Catalina" controls in its user interfaces.

But I don't see much public information about **Catalina**. In a typical SDL Web GUI extension, are implementers allowed to use these controls?

Could someone explain the high-level relationships (or differences) between Anguilla, Catalina, and Lucia. Examples appreciated as well!

Answer (score 3):

Alvin,

I think you can definitely use Catalina controls in your GUI extension since the PublicationMapping extension which was recently released uses them (for the curious one's check the source for Deck usercontrol).

Although I couldn't find any references in docs.sdl.com but if you download the GUI Extension API zip package, there's only 1 object ModalPopupWithCatalinaView that officially uses Catalina control.

But most of the information does remain undocumented so far.

The PublicationMapping extension can be downloaded here: https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/1309